# how to stream a response in nodejs using graphicmagick

Tags: node.js, express

I am having a really difficult time returning an image from nodejs using graphicmagic. The browser is hung on the stream.

I have referenced [NodeJS gm resize and pipe to response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468471/nodejs-gm-resize-and-pipe-to-response) but I still can't make it work.

```
gm = require('gm');

app.get('/text', function (req, res)
{
    gm(200, 400, "#ddff99f3")
    .drawText(10, 50, "from scratch")
    .stream('png', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      stdout.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have missed the 'png' parameter. You have saved my day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so...uh, I just rebooted my machine and it magically worked.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you aren't setting the appropriate Content-type:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png'); // set the header here
```

Do this **before** the call to `gm.drawText`